# Jquery ScrollSpy - works in the example file - doesn't work when I do it

Tags: jquery, scrollspy

I'm using the following script which allows you to detect when elements enter and leave your viewpoint: https://github.com/thesmart/jquery-scrollspy

The example the author provides works great and here's the code for it:

This part basically creates all the elements on the screen:

```
var body = $('body');
for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    var element = $('<div id="tile-' + i + '" class="tile"><h2>Tile #' + i + '</h2></div>');
    body.append(element);
}
```

This is the style for all the elements:

```
.tile {
    width: 290px;
    height: 290px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    margin: 4px;
}
```

And this is the ScrollSpy script that checks when elements enter and leave the viewpoint:

```
$('.tile').on('scrollSpy:enter', function() {
    console.log('enter:', $(this).attr('id'));
});

$('.tile').on('scrollSpy:exit', function() {
    console.log('exit:', $(this).attr('id'));
});

$('.tile').scrollSpy();
```

So far, so good, everything in the example file works. Now what I've tried to do is to manually enter my own element:

```
<div id="tile-220" class="tile"><h2>Tile #220</h2></div>
```

And then use the same ScrollSpy code but updated to see if I can get the same result:

```
$('#tile-220').on('scrollSpy:enter', function() {
    alert("test");
});

$('#tile-220').on('scrollSpy:exit', function() {
    alert("test2");
});

$('#tile-220').scrollSpy();
```

This for some reason, doesn't work. Now if I used instead of #tile-220 one that's generated with the first script, such as #tile-90, it works great, just not with an ID that I added manually. Can anyone help me figure out what I'm missing please?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for manually added tiles as well.

All you need to do is add those in correct position.

Here is the code (snippet):

```
<body>
<script> //Script 1
    var body = $('body');
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        var element = $('<div id="tile-' + i + '" class="tile"><h2>Tile #' + i + '</h2></div>');
        body.append(element);
    }
</script>
<style>
    .tile {
        width: 290px;
        height: 290px;
        float: left;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        margin: 4px;
    }
</style>

<div id="tile-221" class="tile"><h2>Tile #221</h2></div>
<div id="tile-222" class="tile"><h2>Tile #222</h2></div>
<div id="tile-223" class="tile"><h2>Tile #223</h2></div>

<script> //Script 2
    $('.tile').on('scrollSpy:enter', function() {
        console.log('enter:', $(this).attr('id'));
    });

    $('.tile').on('scrollSpy:exit', function() {
        console.log('exit:', $(this).attr('id'));
    });

    $('.tile').scrollSpy();
</script>
</body>
```

It wont work if you add those new divs after Script 2, because as the page loads, script 2 executes for all the divs (tiles) which have been loaded.

**So put your divs before script 2.**

OR you can load the script 2 after all the divs on page has been loaded :

```
<script>
$(function(){ //Addition
    $('.tile').on('scrollSpy:enter', function() {
        console.log('enter:', $(this).attr('id'));
    });

    $('.tile').on('scrollSpy:exit', function() {
        console.log('exit:', $(this).attr('id'));
    });

    $('.tile').scrollSpy();
    });
</script>
```

**Now you can put your new divs anywhere.**

Comment: Or alternatively, just call .scrollSpy on the element inside of a doc.ready function. EDIT: My bad, would need to call all three inside doc.ready..

Comment: Well what I'm trying to do is remove that first part that adds all the elements to the screen as I have no use for it. I just want to use the script for things I manually added and point to specific elements. So lets say I have a logo at the bottom of a website, I want to use the script so when that logo appears in the viewpoint, I get an alert message for example.

Comment: the doc.ready was what I needed... just tried it out, thank you very much!